# Unity3d file in a codeigniter view download error

Tags: php, codeigniter, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load a unity3d web application in a codeigniter view

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Editor extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
           //redirect(base_url('application/editor/editor.php'), 'refresh');
           $this->load->view('editor.html');
        } else {
           redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I placed editor.html and editor.unity3d on the codeigniter view folder and also tried to place the editor.unity3d file on the root folder of the project  but I get the following error in the two cases

`Failed to download data file`

Comment: try making sure that the .unity3d file is in the same directory and has the same name as your trying to call from. In some cases you might have to manually add .unity3d extensions and mine-type's. This is said to be a windows issue.

Comment: I only tested on localhost and it works  fails only if I try load it as a codeigniter view